# Error show modal popup on select date fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am working on fullcalendar and I really want to show popup modal on select date. I have tried, but show the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function` when I click date on fullcalendar.

Here's the header code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable:true,
        header:{
            left:'prev,next today',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>fullcalendar/load",
        selectable:true,
        selectHelper:true,
        minTime: "05:00:00",
        maxTime: "24:30:00",
        slotDuration: '00:15',
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        height: 550,
        select:function(start, end, allDay)
        {
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
        },
        });
     });
```

Here's the html code

```
 <div class="container">
        <div id="calendar" style="width:45%"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: you haven't added the Bootstrap JavaScript file to your page - that's the file which contains the `modal()` function. You've added the Bootstrap CSS, but not the JavaScript.

Comment: P.S. if you're using Bootstrap, then I doubt you need jQueryUI as well...they are two competing UI widget libraries, using both is likely to duplicate functionality and/or cause UX issues where some controls have one style and others have a different style. I suggest you choose which one you actually want the most. (Bootstrap also can help with page layout etc so is probably the more useful, unless you need some very specific widget from jQueryUI)